# could not build wheels error when installing pipenv

Tags: python, package, pipenv

I was installing pipenv and type pip install pipenv on my terminal. This popped up.

[image: Error screenshot]

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Can you upgrade your pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`. It seems the pip version in your machine doesn't support `whl` type packages.

Comment: Already upgraded. However the same error still occurs. "Could not build wheels for pip, since package wheel is not installed." I'm using windows 8

Comment: I typed in pip install wheels and it might have seemed to do the trick. Thanks :)